# Postgresql Column Row matching

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have one table stage which have 2 columns and record is like this

### - C1 C2

- 1  2
- 2  3
- 5  6
- 6  7
- 8  9

Output I need is:

- 1,2,3
- 5,6,7
- 8,9

In first row 1 and 2 and second row 2 and 3 but output I need 1,2,3. 
How to solve this kind of issue, Please provide us query and suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use recursive CTEs for handling tree structures in SQL.

I'm using a CTE called paths to work out the various linked items.
The first part of the Union finds all path starts (items where the c1 value does not exist as a v2 value on another row).

The second part follows the path to the end.  It keeps adding each connection the path text field.

```
with recursive paths as
(
    -- find start points (store start in root)
    select c1 as root, c2, c1 || ',' || c2 as path, 1 as len 
    from stage where not exists (select * from stage t2 where t2.c2 = stage.c1)
union all
    -- add the next item to the path
    select paths.root, stage.c2, paths.path || ',' || stage.c2, len+1 from paths
    inner join stage on paths.c2 = stage.c1
)
select path from paths
where 
  -- only choose longest path from each start point
  not exists (select * from paths x where x.len > paths.len and x.root = paths.root)
order by path
```

Finally I find the longest paths that it found for each start point (root).

CTEs are documented at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/queries-with.html